# Lighthouse flags Array.isArray as legacy Javascript

Tags: pagespeed, lighthouse

Google's PageSpeed tool shows the opportunity "Avoid serving legacy JavaScript to modern browsers" with the following flagged:
[image: Lighthouse Screenshot]

Why is `Array.isArray` "legacy"? I'm not aware this is outdated, or what alternatives is suggested to be better.